# Java Scanner reading something that is not there when reading CSV file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a csv file that goes like this

```
Mike,Smith
Scuba,Steve
John,Doe
```

And java code that goes like this:

```
Scanner file=new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

file.useDelimiter(",");      
while (file.hasNext()){

   String s1=file.next();
   String s2=file.next();
   System.out.println(s1+" "+s2);

}
file.close();
```

I get as output:

```
Mike Smith
Scuba
Steve
John Doe
```

I don't understand what could possibly make this work on the first two names but not the middle one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Smith\nScuba` becomes one token. (There's no `,` separating them.)

Using

```
file.useDelimiter(",|\n");
```

solves the problem.

---

If you happen to be using Java 8, I'd recommend using something like:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))
     .forEach(line -> {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
         s.useDelimiter(",");
         System.out.println(s.next() + " " + s.next());
     });
```

Comment: It seems easier just to use `String.split` at that point. Spawning loads of `Scanner`s isn't fast...

Comment: If split does the job, then sure. Since the OP was using Scanner, I thought that maybe his actual code was a bit more complicated. Regardless, the best approach is probably to use a CSV library, so that stuff like a,"b,c",d is handled correctly as well.